# HTML in JSP and CSS output in Spring application is not appearing the same as local

Tags: html, css, jsp, formatting

So I have created some HTML and CSS for the landing page of my web application that I am developing.
I generally create my design on scratchpad.io before implementing it into STS (IDE that i'm using). Now when I run my application the output of the page looks different to what the HTML i actually designed (and if i open this HTML from my local directory) it looks the same as how I created it.

I have linked my CSS external file in my application just like the rest of my pages (which work).

Does any one have any idea as to why that is? I will upload the two different ouputs (even though it's the same code)

What it should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpUmR.jpg

Same code but in application looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6LIJ.jpg

Thanks!

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Landing</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/landingStyle.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <div class="top-right links">
      <a href="/account/login">Login</a> <a href="/account/signup">Register</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="../styles/ysplanding.jpg" class="brand_logo" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="title m-b-md">
        <div class="nowrap">
          Yorkshire Sculpture Park<br> Employee Portal
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #636b6f;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100vh;
}

.flex-center {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.position-ref {
    position: relative;
}

.top-right {
    position: absolute;
    center: 50px;
    top: 20px;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.9;
    positon: relative;
    padding-top: 2px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.title {
    font-size: 90px;
    position: fixed !important;
}

.m-b-md {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #636b6f;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4;
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 5px;
    left: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.links>a {
    color: #636b6f;
    padding: 0 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: can you add code for this,  jsp and css ?

Comment: done :) @Hemant

Comment: Does your browser console shows any error?

Comment: nope! https://imgur.com/XbRDXQw     @Swati

Answer (score 0):

can you send the path of your file css
but I think the problem is in

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/landingStyle.css">
```

should be

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/landingStyle.css">
```

and alah aalam